# Generating cycles on a strongly connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, markov-chains, decision-theory

I have been thinking about the problem of generating cycles from a given node, on a strongly connected graph. The **goal** is to generate cycles that are *good*, with respect to an objective function $f$.

The obvious approach is to generate all the cycles from the given node and calculate the objective function for each one of them. It's not sufficient to calculate the objective function once, because $f$ is not pure and therefore the result does not depend only on the cycle. However, if a cycle was *good* in the past, there's good chance it will be *good* in the future (at least in the short-term, but I digress).

I was wondering if the solution can be made better if we already have a set of *good* cycles. I thought that we can interpret the graph as a Markov chain if we add edge weights that keep track of how many times the edge was traversed (from the set of already *good* cycles). Then, from a node, we can choose the next one probabilistically using the weights. The downside of this approach is that we're not guaranteed to obtain cycles in a reasonable time or with a reasonable length (very long cycles are very likely not *good*).

Perhaps the latter formulation renders the problem similar to a Markov Decision Process (MDP) problem, but I'm not that familiar with that topic, so here I am asking for references. I don't even know if my problem has a specific name to be honest. Have problems like this one already been studied somewhere? My own research has been quite unsuccessful.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't think the approach will work. The function works on the space of *cycles* but the suggested approach is to weight the *edges*. The reason I'm skeptical is that breaking a cycle into all its constituent edges, you lose a lot of information. Those edges will be in many other cycles too. On the other hand, there is another solution that I don't think you mention in the question. What about maintaining a history of good cycles and then just trying them in order of the most recent one first? If you fail for all the cycles tried, then you just start randomly trying cycles.

Comment: @ColmBhandal Thanks for the input, you're totally right about losing information. Testing cycles that we know were *good* is already something I planned on doing. I formulated the Markov approach because I need a way to discover new *good* cycles -- the brute force approach is slow since the graph is huge.

Comment: Hmmm. In that case I think we might need a little more information about the "good" function. How does it related to single edges vs. cycles? The question formulation at the moment is v. general so not a lot we can do except use $f$ on cycles at the moment. Any more info you can give?